# Applying map function over row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to apply `map` function over rows in 2d array.

Like this:

```
[['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]
```

to

```
[[1, 'apple'], [2, 'banana']]
```

`numpy.apply_along_axis` works, but want to know using `map()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map`, as you might know, iterates over a `iterable` and runs a given function with the current element as its argument, and returns the result of that function.

so to use map with a 2D array, first create a function that takes in each element of the parent 1D array as an argument.

considering your example with array as `[['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]`

```py
def map_function(item):
    return [int(item[0], item[1])]
```

now map will pass each element of the 1D array i,e. `['1', 'apple']` , `['2', 'banana']` , one by one to `map_function` which in turn will convert the `0th` element in the passed list to an `int`.

now just pass this function to `map` along with the `2D` array.

```py
2D_array = [['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]
resultant_2D = list(map(map_function, 2D_array))
# [[1, 'apple'], [2, 'banana']]
```

the solution by @chepner uses `lambda` or anonymous function instead of defining a function to make the code concise, but it all works the same :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
lst = [['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]

[*map(lambda x: [int(x[0]), x[1]], lst)]
# [[1, 'apple'], [2, 'banana']]
```

But I never consider this particularly nice or readable. Compare this with the comprehension

```
[[int(a), b] for a, b in lst]
# [[1, 'apple'], [2, 'banana']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You still map over the entire row, but the function you map will return a new row containing part of the original untouched.

```
>>> list(map(lambda row: [int(row[0]), row[1]], [['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]))
[[1, 'apple'], [2, 'banana']]
```

Since the nested list isn't a single data structure (it's a list of lists), there's no way to *only* map over a column, because there is no explicit column object to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` approach using a helper function as shown in the other answers is best, and works with a list of lists (just as well as with an array, if not better).

`apply_along_axis` is in iterator, so doesn't add anything significant, especially when applied to a 2d array.  Simple iteration on the rows, whether with `map` or list comprehension is just as good, even better.

But if it really is a 2d array, as opposed to a list of lists, there is another option:

```
In [99]: alist = [['1', 'apple'], ['2', 'banana']]
In [100]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [101]: arr
Out[101]: 
array([['1', 'apple'],
       ['2', 'banana']], dtype='<U6')
```

Actually it needs to object dtype, since the result will contain a mix of int and string.  Which takes us back to list of lists.  Anyways:

```
In [102]: arr = np.array(alist, object)
In [103]: arr
Out[103]: 
array([['1', 'apple'],
       ['2', 'banana']], dtype=object)
```

We can access a column, and being object dtype, change it in-place:

```
In [104]: arr[:,0]
Out[104]: array(['1', '2'], dtype=object)
In [105]: arr[:,0].astype(int)
Out[105]: array([1, 2])
In [106]: arr[:,0] = arr[:,0].astype(int)
In [107]: arr
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 'apple'],
       [2, 'banana']], dtype=object)
```

I present this more for educational purposes than as a practical solution.